# how to prevent developer branch in AWS CodeCommit

Tags: aws-codecommit

In my team of 10 developers each developer has his/her own branch (for e.g. A developer has A branch, B developer has B branch) so now I want A developer only push the code into A developer branch but A developer can't push and can't delete B developer branch.

how can I resolve this issue?